# What are the practical considerations when designing a 1-bit DAC with ADC feedback?

Tags: dac

Let's say I have a 1-bit push-pull GPIO and I would like to convert that into a DAC output. To keep things very simple, let's also say that the signal is passed through a 1-st order RC filter. Lastly, in order to precisely control the voltage I would like to sample it with an ADC and use that to trim the GPIO through a simple strategy of

- if `V_{desired} < V_{measured}` --> ON
- if `V_{desired} > V_{measured}` --> OFF

What are the factors I would need to keep in mind in order to achieve a DAC with:

- `>=.1%` voltage accuracy (10-bits or better)
- maximum frequency of `~0.01*X`, where `X` is GPIO output clock frequency

Specifically,

- What practical real-world considerations raise their ugly heads?
- What relative speed does the ADC need?

##### Problem background

For the personal fun of learning, I'd like to use a Zynq to serve as the heart of a hardware simulator, where the Linux core runs the math and FPGA core converts the simulator results into real signals. I need  8 DAC channels for signals which can reach speeds on the 100kHz-1MHz scale.

Comment: Your simple strategy forces the ADC to be a lot higher speed than would be needed if you had some feed-forward PWM behavior.

Comment: @BenVoigt that's true, and to some degree intentional. If the difference in parts is a few dollars more on the BOM then it's worth it to trade money for KISS simplicity. If the difference in parts is "this cannot be purchased", then, well, that's what I want to know!